Login Page for template studio for WinUI
I'm using template studio for winui to create an app on Window. After customizing the app, I want to add an Login UI for the app. The problem is that I can't navigate from the Login into the main UI that template studio has created for me. I find an instruction how to do this UWP follow this docs (https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/dev/docs/navigation.md). But WinUI uses OnLaunched to perform navigation and I don't know how to use it in this situation.
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);

        App.GetService<IAppNotificationService>().Show(
            string.Format("AppNotificationSamplePayload".GetLocalized(), AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        );

        await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
    }

I try to add login page in Views and a Login.cs in ViewModel. I also register for those in App.xaml.cs and PageService.cs but still fail to navigate to the work place. How can I

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/79131740/2411960

Let me know if you still can't fix your issue.

I have this solved here. See where it says Solution - Working.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79178391/template-studio-application-adding-a-login-window-to-be-called-before-the-main
