Template Studio application - Adding a Login Window to be called before the Main Window is displayed
I am building a WinUI 3 Application. I have used the Template Studio to Create a number of pages. Now I am trying to add a log in Window to be called before the main Window.
The Login Screen is of type Window. Here is the code from App.xaml.cs where I am attempting to call my Login Window. An exception occurs when I run this.
I have looked at the documentation for the Application Class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application?view=windows-app-sdk-1.6
From where can I call the login Window? and how can I get my application to progress to the main Window once the login has been successful?
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);

        App.GetService<IAppNotificationService>().Show(string.Format("AppNotificationSamplePayload".GetLocalized(), AppContext.BaseDirectory));
        await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
        
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.Activate();
    }

I have tried the following and the Login starts o.k. But the code in the OnLaunched just continues and completes. So I can't start the MainWindow. How can I hold the code to check after         loginWindow.Activate() has been called ?
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.Activate();

        if (loginWindow.ValidLogin)
        {
            base.OnLaunched(args);

            App.GetService<IAppNotificationService>().Show(string.Format("AppNotificationSamplePayload".GetLocalized(), AppContext.BaseDirectory));
            await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
        }
    }


NEW CODE
  
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      LaunchActivatedEventArgs = args;
      LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
      loginWindow.Activate();
      loginWindow.Closed += LoginWindow_Closed;
  }

  private async void LoginWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
  {
      if ((sender as LoginWindow)?.ValidLogin is true)
      {
          base.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs);
          //Thread.Sleep(5000);
          App.GetService<IAppNotificationService>().Show(string.Format("AppNotificationSamplePayload".GetLocalized(), AppContext.BaseDirectory));
          await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs);
      }
  }


In a WinUI 3 application, if you're trying to show a login window before the main window, you can indeed show the login window from the OnLaunched method of App.xaml.cs. However, you need to handle the flow correctly, especially since the Activate method only displays the window but doesn't necessarily stop the execution of the app until the login completes. You need to ensure that the login window blocks the main app window from appearing until the login process is successful.

Depends on what you want. You can just change the Window.Content to any UIElement but you wont get an animation. You can have a Frame as the Window.Content then you can have animations using Frame.Navigate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame

Only have one Window, but two Pages. A LoginPage and a MainPage

You need to be more specific about the issue. What do you mean by "run"? You mean you hit F5 on Debug mode without any breakpoints? or you mean Release mode? Is it before the login? or after the login? You need to narrow down the origin of the error by reducing code (features).

I am in Debug mode. With No Break Points I get the error - The program '[30988] TestWinUI3App1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).   If I place a break point on the await App.GetService...    and wait for about 10 seconds then press F10 again the program continues to the MainWindow with no issues.

Can you share code of your ActivationService? Is it just the default code created by the TemplateStudio? or did you add some features to it?

The issue is inside ActivationService.ActivateAsync() right?

The Solution as outlined by Andrew Works.  The LoginWindow_Closed method needs LaunchActivatedEventArgs, which I got around by creating a property of type LaunchActivatedEventArgs.

Let's say that your Window for login is named LoginWindow and it has a Successed property to check the login result.
App.xaml.cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnLaunched(args);
    var loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
    loginWindow.Closed += OnLoginWindowClosed();
    loginWindow.Activate();
}

private async void LoginWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
{
    if ((sender as LoginWindow)?.Successed is not true)
    {
        // Failed!
        return;
    }

    // Successed!
    App.GetService<IAppNotificationService>().Show(string.Format("AppNotificationSamplePayload".GetLocalized(), AppContext.BaseDirectory));
    await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
}


You can find more detailed sample code here.

I tried this code - see my comments above

Solution: I had to create a local event based on the loginWindow login button click. The key part was the loginWindow can only be closed after the Activation Service is activated. The reason I had to do this is because the login Window can only be closed after the main window Activation Service has started.
services.AddTransient<LoginWindow>();  // When Adding Services DI

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     var loginWindow = App.GetService<LoginWindow>();
     loginWindow.LoginButton.Click += async (sender, e) => {
         if (loginWindow.ValidLogin)              {
             base.OnLaunched(args);
             await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
             loginWindow.Close();
         }
     };
     loginWindow.Activate();
 }


@JeremyCaney I have updated the answer above. I am not able to log any new questions on stack overflow. Is there a reason?

I can’t speak to your specifics, but StackOverflow does have question bans for contributors who have posted a number of questions which then get closed or deleted, so that could be a factor. You might ask on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Here's something you can clone https://github.com/tom-huntington/App2
You dont' want two Windows but rather two Pages
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_window = new Window();
        var p = new LoginPage();
        p.SubmitButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
            m_window.Content = new MainPage();
        };
        m_window.Content = p;
        m_window.Activate();
    }
    private Window m_window;
}

Add new Item > WinUI > Page
<Page x:Class="App2.LoginPage" ...>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <Button x:Name="SubmitButton" Content="Login" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>

Renamed MainWindow -> MainPage
<Page x:Class="App2.MainPage" ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="MainPage"/>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>


Thank you but I want 2 separate Windows. Not 2 Pages
